# Tornado chart converting from d3 v3 to v6

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to attempt to convert this Tornado chart from D3 v3 to v6, but not sure how to go about it.

https://bl.ocks.org/lmatteis/d0f7533895da2e59cd6f62f3589fd8eb

Some assistance would be amazing! Currently this is running with V3 of D3.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar--positive {
  fill: #9BCCF5;
}

.bar--negative {
  fill: pink;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
</style>
<body>
<p id="example"></p>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

function tornadoChart() {
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 100},
    width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, height], 0.1);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(7)

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .tickSize(0)

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  function chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(data) {

      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.interactions; })).nice();
      y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.age; }));

      var minInteractions = Math.min.apply(Math, data.map(function(o){return o.interactions;}))
      yAxis.tickPadding(Math.abs(x(minInteractions) - x(0)) + 10);

      var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data)

      bar.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", function(d) { return "bar bar--" + (d.interactions < 0 ? "negative" : "positive"); })
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(Math.min(0, d.interactions)); })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.age); })
          .attr("width", function(d) { return Math.abs(x(d.interactions) - x(0)); })
          .attr("height", y.rangeBand())

      bar.enter().append('text')
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("x", function(d,i) {
              return x(Math.min(0, d.interactions)) + (Math.abs(x(d.interactions) - x(0)) / 2);
          })
          .attr("y", function(d,i) {
              return y(d.age) + (y.rangeBand() / 2);
          })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function (d) { return d.interactions; })

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
          .call(yAxis);
    });
  }

  return chart;
}

var data = {"BMW":[{"age":"18-24","gender":"male","interactions":21600},{"age":"18-24","gender":"female","interactions":-5500},{"age":"25-34","gender":"male","interactions":19500},{"age":"25-34","gender":"female","interactions":-5000},{"age":"35-44","gender":"male","interactions":10700},{"age":"35-44","gender":"female","interactions":-3500},{"age":"45-54","gender":"male","interactions":5700},{"age":"45-54","gender":"female","interactions":-2400},{"age":"55-64","gender":"male","interactions":2500},{"age":"55-64","gender":"female","interactions":-1100},{"age":"65+","gender":"male","interactions":1600},{"age":"65+","gender":"female","interactions":-600}],"Ford Mustang":[{"age":"18-24","gender":"male","interactions":7600},{"age":"18-24","gender":"female","interactions":-800},{"age":"25-34","gender":"male","interactions":7100},{"age":"25-34","gender":"female","interactions":-900},{"age":"35-44","gender":"male","interactions":5100},{"age":"35-44","gender":"female","interactions":-800},{"age":"45-54","gender":"male","interactions":3500},{"age":"45-54","gender":"female","interactions":-600},{"age":"55-64","gender":"male","interactions":1400},{"age":"55-64","gender":"female","interactions":-300},{"age":"65+","gender":"male","interactions":600},{"age":"65+","gender":"female","interactions":-200}],"Ford Motor Company":[{"age":"25-34","gender":"male","interactions":4300},{"age":"25-34","gender":"female","interactions":-800},{"age":"18-24","gender":"male","interactions":4200},{"age":"18-24","gender":"female","interactions":-700},{"age":"35-44","gender":"male","interactions":3000},{"age":"35-44","gender":"female","interactions":-600},{"age":"45-54","gender":"male","interactions":1800},{"age":"45-54","gender":"female","interactions":-500},{"age":"55-64","gender":"male","interactions":800},{"age":"55-64","gender":"female","interactions":-300},{"age":"65+","gender":"male","interactions":500},{"age":"65+","gender":"female","interactions":-200}]};

for (var i in data) {
  var chart = tornadoChart()
  d3.select("#example")
      .datum(data[i])
      .call(chart);
}

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required updates are to your scales and axes:

```
  var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, height], 0.1);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(7)

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .tickSize(0)
```

Becomes:

```
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scaleBand()
      .rangeRound([0, height])
      .padding(0.1);
      
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
      .scale(x)
      .ticks(7);

  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
      .scale(y)
      .tickSize(0)
```

Where the major change is conversion of `scale.ordinal` to `scaleBand` - which leads onto replacing references to `rangeBand` with `bandwidth` e.g. replace:

```
.attr("height", y.rangeBand())
```

With

```
.attr("height", y.bandwidth())
```

Example v6 code:

```js
function tornadoChart() {
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 100},
    width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scaleBand()
      .rangeRound([0, height])
      .padding(0.1);
      
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
      .scale(x)
      .ticks(7);

  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
      .scale(y)
      .tickSize(0)

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  function chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(data) {

      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.interactions; })).nice();
      y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.age; }));

      var minInteractions = Math.min.apply(Math, data.map(function(o){return o.interactions;}))
      yAxis.tickPadding(Math.abs(x(minInteractions) - x(0)) + 10);

      var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data)

      bar.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", function(d) { return "bar bar--" + (d.interactions < 0 ? "negative" : "positive"); })
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(Math.min(0, d.interactions)); })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.age); })
          .attr("width", function(d) { return Math.abs(x(d.interactions) - x(0)); })
          .attr("height", y.bandwidth())

      bar.enter().append('text')
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("x", function(d,i) {
              return x(Math.min(0, d.interactions)) + (Math.abs(x(d.interactions) - x(0)) / 2);
          })
          .attr("y", function(d,i) {
              return y(d.age) + (y.bandwidth() / 2);
          })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function (d) { return d.interactions; })

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
          .call(yAxis);
    });
  }

  return chart;
}

var data = {"BMW":[{"age":"18-24","gender":"male","interactions":21600},{"age":"18-24","gender":"female","interactions":-5500},{"age":"25-34","gender":"male","interactions":19500},{"age":"25-34","gender":"female","interactions":-5000},{"age":"35-44","gender":"male","interactions":10700},{"age":"35-44","gender":"female","interactions":-3500},{"age":"45-54","gender":"male","interactions":5700},{"age":"45-54","gender":"female","interactions":-2400},{"age":"55-64","gender":"male","interactions":2500},{"age":"55-64","gender":"female","interactions":-1100},{"age":"65+","gender":"male","interactions":1600},{"age":"65+","gender":"female","interactions":-600}],"Ford Mustang":[{"age":"18-24","gender":"male","interactions":7600},{"age":"18-24","gender":"female","interactions":-800},{"age":"25-34","gender":"male","interactions":7100},{"age":"25-34","gender":"female","interactions":-900},{"age":"35-44","gender":"male","interactions":5100},{"age":"35-44","gender":"female","interactions":-800},{"age":"45-54","gender":"male","interactions":3500},{"age":"45-54","gender":"female","interactions":-600},{"age":"55-64","gender":"male","interactions":1400},{"age":"55-64","gender":"female","interactions":-300},{"age":"65+","gender":"male","interactions":600},{"age":"65+","gender":"female","interactions":-200}],"Ford Motor Company":[{"age":"25-34","gender":"male","interactions":4300},{"age":"25-34","gender":"female","interactions":-800},{"age":"18-24","gender":"male","interactions":4200},{"age":"18-24","gender":"female","interactions":-700},{"age":"35-44","gender":"male","interactions":3000},{"age":"35-44","gender":"female","interactions":-600},{"age":"45-54","gender":"male","interactions":1800},{"age":"45-54","gender":"female","interactions":-500},{"age":"55-64","gender":"male","interactions":800},{"age":"55-64","gender":"female","interactions":-300},{"age":"65+","gender":"male","interactions":500},{"age":"65+","gender":"female","interactions":-200}]};



for (var i in data) {
  var chart = tornadoChart()
  d3.select("#example")
      .datum(data[i])
      .call(chart);
}
```

```css
.bar--positive {
  fill: #9BCCF5;
}

.bar--negative {
  fill: pink;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.3.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<p id="example"></p>
```